# Is it possible to define multiple messages for the same http status code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Required authority:  CREATE_W"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message1"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message2"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message3"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message4"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message5"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "message6"),
})
public DetailedDto add(
```

I have defined some validator that can return different messages for some payload. Currently only the first message is displayed in Swagger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design it will take the first message for same error code. If you need to represent multiple possible errors, you'd need to do that within the message/model of a single error instance.